# How get the language, which current user set in his profile?

Tags: wordpress

How get the language in wordpress, which current user set in his profile?

Something like:

```
$language = get_current_user()->language;
if ($language == 'en') {
      //gogogo;
}
```

Comment: are you using wpml or any plugin which is having the language converter?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_locale - check this

Comment: I think you can try this steps. 1. get_locale, 2 save to user meta. 3. you can get language when user login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the user meta `locale` (which is set in user profile), you can try this:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_locale = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'locale', true);
if($user_locale == 'en_EN') {
  // gogogo;
}
```

Greetz, Bjorn

Answer (score 0):

In [version 4.7.0](https://wordpress.org/documentation/wordpress-version/version-4-7/) (December 6, 2016), WordPress introduced the [get_user_locale()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_locale/) function which retrieves the locale of a user. The function falls back to `get_locale()` and returns the global locale if no user matching the criteria is found.

The `get_user_locale()` function can be passed to an optional parameter that can be either a user ID or a user object. If no parameter is provided, the function will try to retrieve the locale of the user who is currently logged in.

Example when specifying the user:

```php
<?php

$user_locale = get_user_locale( 15 );
// the locale of user 15
// or the global locale if no user with that ID was found
```

Example for the user who is currently logged in:

```php
$user_locale = get_user_locale();
// the locale of the user who is currently logged in
// or the global locale for guests
```